# Using Android In-App Billing classes for multiple apps, in a shared library project

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-billing

I'm using the Google Play billing API (Version 3) for all my applications which use a shared library project (also created by me) and I have a question regarding the setup for the helper classes classes (in package .inappbilling.util) and the IInAppBillingService.aidl file (that generates IInAppBillingService.java class):

Is it ok (good practice) to store those files in my shared library and then use them in all my apps or do I have to create a copy in every project for those applications (in the case that the files generated by android plugin are somehow dependent on the project )?

Comment: Also, I've noticed that some tutorials show how to modify the Security class so that the purchase flow can be simulated using the static sku. If there are more modifications to the billing helper classes, is it ok to put them in the shared library for all my apps ?

Answer (score 0):

Store common files in a shared library.

Comment: Sorry that this isn't posted as a comment -- I don't have sufficient reputation.